# I want to use fields in an object to filter product

Tags: django, django-views

Here is my model:

```
class PromotedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name="When do you want your advert to start", null=True, blank=True)
    stop_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name="When do you want your advert to end", null=True, blank=True)
    is_promotion_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(
        MerchantProfile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Product Title",
                            max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    is_digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductCategory, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='products')
    product_video_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
    product_video = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)

    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)



class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                              default="category/blank.jpg", upload_to='category')
    icon = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True,
                             default="category/icon.jpg", upload_to='category')
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, default=None)
```

I want to filter our promoted products under a category, say we have the category "computers"
and a promoted product "Laptop" under the category "computers".

i want to filter my PromotedProduct table with products under the category 'computers', i tried this but got an error, any help will be appreciated:

```
def promoted_products(request)
    cat = ProductCategory.objects.get(slug='computers')
    promoted = PromotedProduct.objects.filter(product.category=cat
    is_active=True, stop_date__gte=datetime.now().date(), start_date__lte=datetime.now().date())  
    print(promoted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```
def promoted_products(request)
    cat = ProductCategory.objects.get(slug='computers')
    promoted = PromotedProduct.objects.filter(product__category=cat,is_active=True, stop_date__gte=datetime.now().date(), start_date__lte=datetime.now().date())
    print(promoted)
```

Answer (score 0):

sfirst, when you get an error it is always helpful to add the error text as part of the question.

second the query you are trying to make should be written like that:

```
def promoted_products(request)
    #if you need multiple categories, you can pull the ids
    #l_slugsList = []
    #cat_ids = ProductCategory.objects.filter(slug__in=l_slugsList)
    
    #single category
    cat = ProductCategory.objects.get(slug='computers')
   
    #get the subset of products for the specific category
    #OR if multiple categories use 'category_id__in=cat_id' instead
    #of the id filter
    product_ids = Product.objects.filter(category_id=cat.id)\
                                 .values_list('id',flat=True)
    
    #pull the promoted products for the subset of products
    #the product_ids query allows you to drop the reference
    #to a related object which is generally preferred for 
    #performance reasons
    promoted = PromotedProduct.objects.filter(\
                                 product_id__in=product_ids,\
                                 is_active=True,\                                         
                                 stop_date__gte=datetime.now().date(),\ 
                                 start_date__lte=datetime.now().date())  
                              #.select_related('product')
    #if you want to work on the product of the promoted product is efficient
    #to request it beforehand. This will result in less sql queries.
    #in order to do that, uncomment the [select_related][1] part 

    print(promoted)
```